# Position a div bottom left in a float div

Tags: html, css, styles, position

Look at this please.

http://jsfiddle.net/snw5rgx9/3/

or this new stackoverflow code snippet.

```css
.image {
    float: left;
    margin-right: 10px;
}

.text {
    height: 100px;
    position: relative;
}

.bottom-left {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="image">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100" />
    </div>
    <div class="text">
        asd
        <div class="bottom-left">
            Delete &bull; Edit
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I have a problem with the position of a div in a div bottom left which is floated left.

Also

```
X | Text
  | Bottom
```

It looks like this.

```
X | Text
Bottom
```

[image]

Thanks in Advance for informations.

Comment: and houw would you like it to be? what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Like yours but without margin :) -> http://jsfiddle.net/snw5rgx9/5/

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if I fully undestand the question, but try adding  margin-left for .text with the value of the image width + 10 (to align top text, which has 10px margin-left, like this:

```
.text {
    height: 100px;
    position: relative;
    margin-left: 110px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/snw5rgx9/5/

Comment: :D That was my idea, too. But i think there is a better solution?

Answer (score 0):

After apply the float, You need to clear the next div.

If you want clear idea about clear style [Click this link..](http://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/c/clear/)

> .text {
>       height: 100px;
>       clear:both;
>       position: relative;
>   }

Comment: Doesnt work. http://i.imgur.com/odcR5zB.png But maybe your link explain me how to do this better.

Comment: How do you want to display the second div?

Comment: Thanks! I modified it for my use: http://jsfiddle.net/mo3oxxxd/3/  Please write a full answer for ok tick.

Comment: Yes you're not using margin-left so that's the answer. I forget the overflow attribute etc.

Comment: I cant accept the first answer because your real answer is an comment ^^